# Telegram bot won't respond even doe webhook is set

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

The code for the bot is currently hosted on a Cloudflare worker, and there are no errors being reported from that end. Additionally, upon investigation of the Botfather side, everything seems to be functioning normally as well. However, despite attempting various solutions such as changing bots, tokens, and chat groups, the issue remains.

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  const { pathname } = new URL(request.url)

  if (pathname === '/') {
    return new Response('Hello! This is a Telegram bot. Send me a message.')
  }

  const { text } = await request.json()

  if (text.startsWith('/start')) {
    return new Response('Welcome to the bot! Use the /help command to see available options.')
  } else if (text.startsWith('/help')) {
    return new Response('Available commands:\n/scrape - scrapes videos from the specified website and sends them to the Telegram chat.\n/<example> - scrapes posts from the specified website and sends them to the Telegram chat.')
  } else if (text.startsWith('/scrape')) {
    const videoUrl = await scrapeVideoUrl('<example url>')
    const message = `Here's the latest video: ${videoUrl}`
    await sendMessageToChatId(message)
    return new Response('OK')
  } else if (text.startsWith('/<example>')) {
    const post = await scrapePost('<example url>')
    const message = `Here's the latest post: ${post.title}\n${post.url}`
    await sendMessageToChatId(message)
    return new Response('OK')
  } else {
    return new Response('Invalid command. Use the /help command to see available options.')
  }
}

async function scrapeVideoUrl(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url)
  const html = await response.text()

  const cheerio = require('cheerio')
  const $ = cheerio.load(html)

  const videoUrl = $('div.media > a').attr('href')

  return videoUrl
}

async function scrapePost(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url)
  const html = await response.text()

  const cheerio = require('cheerio')
  const $ = cheerio.load(html)

  const post = {
    title: $('div.content h1').text(),
    url: url
  }

  return post
}

async function sendMessageToChatId(message) {
  const telegramApiUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage";
  const chatId = "<id>";

  const response = await fetch(telegramApiUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      chat_id: chatId,
      text: message
    })
  })
}
```

There is zero response on the telegram side, even doe on web side everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue, searched a lot but found no solution. But with lots of tries i figured out if url contains underscores _ , then webhook doesn't work. I replaced underscores with - and it worked suddenly

like for example `https://project_name.user.worker.dev` wont work

try changing it to `https://project-name.user.worker.dev` instead and it should work